# Can't parse a 1904 date in ARPA format (email date)

Tags: python, email, datetime, parsing

I'm processing an IMAP mailbox and running into trouble parsing the dates using the mxDateTime package. In particular, early dates like "Fri, 1 Jan 1904 00:43:25 -0400" is causing trouble:

```
>>> import mx.DateTime
>>> import mx.DateTime.ARPA
>>> mx.DateTime.ARPA.ParseDateTimeUTC("Fri, 1 Jan 1904 00:43:25 -0400").gmtoffset()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
Error: cannot convert value to a time value
>>> mx.DateTime.ARPA.ParseDateTimeUTC("Thu, 1 Jan 2009 00:43:25 -0400").gmtoffset()
<mx.DateTime.DateTimeDelta object for '-08:00:00.00' at 1497b60>
>>>
```

Note that an almost identical date from 2009 works fine. I can't find any description of date limitations in mxDateTime itself. Any ideas why this might be?

Thx,

Ramon

Comment: Please post `mx.__version__`. I'm not able to reproduce the error using version 3.1.2

Comment: mx.__version__ is 3.1.2, running on Windows

Comment: The real question is, who has been sending you e-mail from 1904?

Comment: yeah I know :-), this is a user's mailbox that clear at some point was using a buggy mail client that messed up the date. I'm just looking for a way to gracefully parse and pass these dates through for now.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that the mxDateTime object only handles datetimes which fall after [the Unix Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)?

Comment: Theortically now; one of the claimed features of this package is that it handles this. From the docs intro at http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/mxDateTime.pdf: "Apart from handling dates before the Unix epoch (1.1.1970) they also correctly work with dates beyond the Unix time limit (currently with Unix
time values being commonly encoded using 32bit integers, the limit is reached in 2038) and thus is Year 2000 and Year 2038 safe."

Comment: Well, never hurts to check - try passing it a date in 1970, and then 1969?

Comment: Looks like that was it:

    >>> mx.DateTime.ARPA.ParseDateTimeUTC("Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:43:25 -0400").gmtoffset()
    <mx.DateTime.DateTimeDelta object for '-08:00:00.00' at 1497b60>
    >>> mx.DateTime.ARPA.ParseDateTimeUTC("Wed, 1 Jan 1969 00:43:25 -0400").gmtoffset()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
    Error: cannot convert value to a time value

Comment: (I can't get markup to work in these replies -- are replies plain text only?)

Comment: There's some markup that works in comments - **bold** (enclosing text in double asterisks: `**bold**`), *italic* (single asterisks: `*italic*`), and `code` (backticks `\`code\``).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with the help of the eGenix folks. It is an Epoch problem, but you can work around it by manually extracting the timezone offset and then re-applying explicitly:

```
>>> s = "Wed, 1 Jan 1969 00:43:25 -0400"
>>> delta = ParseDateTime(s) - ParseDateTimeUTC(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'ParseDateTime' is not defined
>>> delta = mx.DateTime.ARPA.ParseDateTime(s) - mx.DateTime.ARPA.ParseDateTimeUTC(s)
>>> mx.DateTime.ARPA.str(mx.DateTime.ARPA.ParseDateTime(s), delta)
'Wed, 01 Jan 1969 00:43:25 -0400'
>>>
```

Thanks everyone!